# Wordpress: Using the category slug get the category ID using mysql query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

basically, I have a cookie with the category slug stored, using this data I want to query the database and return the ID of the category.

I am new to mysql and this seems like an advanced query that may need to use joins, any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/File:WP3.0-ERD.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
FROM   wp_terms
  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy USING (term_id)
WHERE  wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
   AND wp_terms.slug = ?
```

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 3):

Check out the example on the page for [get_category_by_slug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug):

```
<?php 
  $idObj = get_category_by_slug('slug'); 
  $id = $idObj->term_id;
?>
```

More importantly, if you already have the slug stored, why not just store the id along with it in order to avoid having to query for the ID each time?

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, it'd probably be easiest for you to add the following to any WordPress page:

```
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
global $wpdb;
print_r($wpdb->queries);
```

and then run the original code from this post. This will enable you to see the queries that WordPress performed in order to get the category and associated data, and you can copy them and use them in your code.

Comment: It needs to be done using mysql as this is in a file that is separate from wordpress, unless you had a way around that? And because of the set up, I am no able to.

Comment: Check out my edit above, that should help you with what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the name and slug are stored on the same table, so something like this should do it (only mysql, no WP Query involved):

```
SELECT term_id as id FROM wp_terms WHERE slug = 'slug-here';
```

Comment: Nope that does not work, I have also outputted the entire table to have a look and the categories are not listed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WordPress native function [**`get_term_by`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) ex:

```
$term = get_term_by('slug',$SLUG_FROM_COOKIE,'category');
```

and now`$term` is a term object so you can use `$term->ID`